# Elasticsearch Nest query to trim white spaces while comparing fields with provided value

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am working with Nest API for elastic search and I am looking for some solution where we can trim white spaces while comparing fields with provided value.

**Problem:-**

Elastic DB have field "customField1" ="Jinesh          " and I am passing value to search ="Jinesh" which is not comparing and providing no result.

**What I am looking for:-**

It should search exact provided search value by ignoring white spaces in elastic field values.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to solve your issue depending on your requirements. The one that best fits your description, in my opinion, is using the `Regexp` query:

```
var result =
            await
                client.SearchAsync<object>(
                    searchDescriptor =>
                        searchDescriptor.Query(
                            queryDescriptor =>
                                queryDescriptor.Regexp(
                                    regex => regex.OnField("customField1").Value(" *Jinesh *"))));
```

Other options would be using `Prefix`, `Wildcard` or `MatchPhrasePrefix`.

**However, this goes against Elasticsearch best practices.**

The "Elasticsearch way" of doing this would be to analyze the property using an analyzer that strips the whitespace characters (meaning it'll be saved in the database without the whitespace). A couple of analyzers that do that are the `standard` analyzer (default analyzer) or the `whitespace` analyzer. You could also add a custom analyzer and use the `Trim Token Filter` with your tokenizer.

You can do that by [configuring your index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/configuring-analyzers.html).

If you require a particular analyzer that doesn't allow you to use any whitespace trimming, it is suggested by Elasticsearch that you add to your index a property that is simply a copy of the property in question (i.e. "customField1"), which could then use a better suiting analyzer for this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. it really helped me to move ahead.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `string` property on your POCO will be indexed as an analyzed `string` field in 2.x, or as an analyzed `text` field in 5.x with a not_analyzed `keyword` subfield. The analyzer in both versions is the **[Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/analysis-standard-analyzer.html)** which, amongst other things, splits the input character stream on whitespace characters and removes them when generating tokens.

You can see the effect of an analyzer on a given string input with the **[Analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/indices-analyze.html)**. In [Sense](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/sense/current/installing.html)/[Console](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-5-0-0-released)

```
GET _analyze
{
  "text": ["Jinesh          "],
  "analyzer": "standard"
}
```

returns

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "jinesh",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

These are the tokens that would be stored in the inverted index and search against.

To then find a match for this with NEST, you can use the [`match` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/query-dsl-match-query.html)

```cs
void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
            .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Person>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    );

    client.Index(new Person
    {   
        Name = "Jinesh          "
    }, i => i.Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor));

    var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .Match(m => m
                .Field(f => f.Name)
                .Query("Jinesh")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The response from the search is

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.2876821,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "default-index",
        "_type" : "person",
        "_id" : "AVjeLMxUCwxm5eXshs-y",
        "_score" : 0.2876821,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Jinesh          "
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. it really helped me to move ahead.